# Force non-www https mode for a dirctory and its sub-folders

Tags: htaccess, wordpress, https, opencart, folder

My root website (`example.com`) and its folder (`example.com/folder`) have two different CMS (Opencart for `example.com` and WordPress for `example.com/folder`).

I use this code in `example.com` to force non-www https mode:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This code works perfectly for `example.com` and all its sub-folders expect for `example.com/folder` with WordPress CMS.

What should I do?

Comment: Does your WordPress site in the subdirectory not already have its own `.htaccess` file (for pretty permalinks)?

Comment: Yes, It has own .htaccess file.

Comment: Sorry, at first I assumed these directives were adversely affecting the WordPress site, but I guess you meant that they weren't doing _anything_ for the WordPress site? See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You presumably want these directives to apply to the WordPress installation in the subdirectory as well - but it is currently not doing anything for WordPress I assume?

This is expected behaviour if you have enabled WordPress "pretty" permalinks. Because the mod_rewrite directives in the WordPress `.htaccess` file (in the subdirectory) will completely override the mod_rewrite directives in the parent `.htaccess` file. The mod_rewrite directives in the parent `.htaccess` will not be processed.

You can utilise mod_rewrite inheritance, but this depends on what other mod_rewrite directives you have in the parent `.htaccess` file and on your server config (particularly the Apache version). Besides, it is probably beneficial to keep the OpenCart and WordPress configs as separate as much as possible.

The easiest solution is to reproduce these directives at the start of the `.htaccess` file in the WordPress subdirectory. However, you can't simply copy them without alteration, otherwise you will likely lose the subdirectory from the redirected URL when requesting the `www` subdomain.

For example, try the following at the top of the `example.com/folder/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Code works properly for HTTP folder and all its subdirectories and also for all www subdirectories, but only for case {www.example.com/folder/} , root folder (WordPress root folder) will be redirect to root HTTPS domain!

Comment: The issue has been resolved. Also, the last problem was fixed by clearing the browser's cache.